# passport node authenticate success

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am working on implementing the passport authentication into my node application, and I am unable to understand why there needs to be a redirect before I can access the response (res) attribute?

```
app.get('/api/loginFailure', function(req, res) {
    res.status(401).json({message: 'Login Failed', success: true});
});

app.get('/api/loginSuccess', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({message:'Welcome!', success: true});

});


// process the login form
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', { 
    successRedirect: '/api/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/api/loginFailure'}));
```

As you can see, I use the successRedirect to access a different route in order to send back a json response. I do not want the node api redirecting the actual application as the intention is for it to be agnostic to the front end.

The local login strategy is as follows. I suspect my difficulties may be in how I return from the method;

```
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({
                'local.email': email
            },

            function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                // if no user is found, return the message
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                }

                // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
                }

                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, user);
            });

    }));
```

I intend to remove all of the flashdata and what not, but for now just being able to collapse the 2 additional api routes into the /api/login would be great.

Answer (score 3):

> I am unable to understand why there needs to be a redirect before I can access the response (res) attribute?

If you checked the [passport documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), instead of copying your code from [this guide](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), which is meant for another type of use, you would find out that it doesn't always require redirects.

You can also use it in the following way:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  }
);
```

Comment: That is what the guide was for no? A starting point? I understand that I can do what you highlighted above, what I do not yet understand is how to return from a custom strategy such that the same logic above can be applied.

Comment: You already tried to use the same `passport.use()` block with this?

Comment: I have tried app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {}); but the attribute res is not available. That is why I think my return statements in my local strategy are incorrect.